# Make checkout shipping postcode field not required in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout

So I followed the instructions from: [Link](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/) to change required field of a post code.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'wc_optional_billing_fields' );
function wc_optional_billing_fields( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['shipping_postcode']['required'] = false;

    return $address_fields;
}
```

Unfortunately instead of changing the required it makes a second field:
[Image](https://i.gyazo.com/929f9aced8fe836ff5ea4ac1708e7c83.png)

Can anyone point out what is the issue here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> That happens because you are using `woocommerce_billing_fields` hook filter that is managing only **billing fields** for a **shipping** postcode field…

You could try to use `woocommerce_shipping_fields` filter hook, but it will not work because the **postcode** checkout field is a very **special field** that can only be set to not required using the following hooked function:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'customise_postcode_fields' );
function customise_postcode_fields( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['postcode']['required'] = false;

    return $address_fields;
}
```

So as you can see it acts on both **billing and shipping postcode** fields. Apparently is not possible to make it only for shipping postcode field only for both billing and shipping fields.

Official documentation tutorials: [Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)

Comment: Ah, thank you very much for pointing this out, as I tried woocommerce_billing_fields too and it still didn't work!

Comment: @Exsedor I have tried all possible ways, the only one that works for your case is the one in my answer…